# Rails given a string, how to convert it to an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

my table has Attachment.attachment_content_type which is of type string. Values look like this:

```
[]
[image/png]
[application/msword, application/word, application/x-msword, application/x-word, text/plain]
```

What I want to do is get the first item if any.

I'm trying with:

```
attachment.attachment_content_type[0]
```

But that just returns [ and not 'application/msword'

Should I use a split or is there a better way with ruby on rails to tell rails this is an array? Thanks

Comment: The answers below are correct solutions.  I'm a little curious about why these are being stored in a somewhat difficult-to-parse string.  If you control the code, consider using ActiveRecord's `serialize` to store/retrieve a real Ruby array, or consider creating a has_many relationship to another table (probably overkill for this).

Comment: This is being done by rails paperclip gem

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat foo.rb 

strings = [
  "[]",
  "[image/png]",
  "[application/msword, application/word, application/x-msword, application/x-word, text/plain]"
]

strings.each do |string|
  array = string[1...-1].split(/[\s,]+/)
  puts array[0]
end

$ ruby foo.rb 

image/png
application/msword
```

Comment: By way of explanation for Rachel, the value `"[]"` and others are Strings, so must be parsed and turned into arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`attachment.attachment_content_type[1..-2].split(',').map(&:strip)` will return the contents of the string as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `gsub!` and `scan`.

```
mimetypes.gsub!(/([\[\]])/, '')
mime_array = mimetypes.scan(/, /)
```

See the [String API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) for more interesting methods along with [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) for regex testing :)